# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index gridview

Tags: asp.net, grid, rowcommand

My grid has only one row (always) based on unique condition in database. When I try to edit using `Rowcommand` am getting error as

> "Index was out of range"

Here is grid code and asp.net code:

```
protected void grdedittemplate_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "Update") {
        int index = e.commandargument;
        Label L0 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[0].Controls[1];
        value.Text = L0.Text;
        Label L1 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[1].Controls[1];
        value1.Text = L1.Text;
        Label L2 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[2].Controls[1];
        value2.Text = L2.Text;
        Label L3 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[3].Controls[1];
        value3.Text = L3.Text;
        Label L4 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[4].Controls[1];
        value4.Text = L4.Text;
        Label L5 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[5].Controls[1];
        value5.Text = .text Label L6 = (Label) grd.Rows[index].Cells[6].Controls[1];
        value6.Text = L6.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: am getting in error in Line 4 assinging L0... My grid has AutoGenerate Columns="False" and am binding 7 columns from Database.. new to stack overflow, very difficult in posting my code.

Comment: Also please share your aspx

Comment: Thanks Taleeb.. I have achieved with buttons outside the grid.